# Why is Google Tag Manager Event not shown as own event in tagassistant?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a tag für purchase in GTM. Actually I have created some to test it.
But in tagassistant the tag is shown inside 'Container Loaded' and not as own event.
I wonder why this is so and if it is fine.

[image: tagassistant]

The tag details are like this:
[image: Tag Details]

For the other events like add_to_cart they are shown in the left column in tagassistant.

How can I have it as own event in the left column?